# Why does my javascript function only work sometimes? Imported into reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a website using react app, and I have imported an external vanilla javascript. It DOES work, but only sometimes, other times it doesn't seem to register the click event. As far as I can tell, there's nothing different that happens between when it does work and when it doesn't (I want one body content to be shown and the other two hidden when something is cliked e.g., past, current, future, loads the content onto the same page). I've tried this both with and without addEventListener in  the vanilla app, its the same issue regardless. I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')` a lot, exchange 'style' with addEventListener for the version with those included.

I'm very new to react app so I assume there's a problem with how I'm connecting the two files?

exhibitions.js (react)

```
import React from 'react'
import './exhibitions.css'
import { setPastOn, setCurrentOn, setFutureOn } from './exhibitions-nav.js'

export default function Exhibitions() {
    return (
        <main className="main-exhibitions">
            <div className="title">
                    <div className="title-line-left"></div>
                    <h2>exhibitions</h2>
                    <div className="title-line-right"></div>
                </div>
            <div className="exhibitions-navbar">
                <span className="nav-past" onClick={setPastOn}>past</span>
                <span className="nav-current" onClick={setCurrentOn}>current</span>
                <span className="nav-future" onClick={setFutureOn}>future</span>
            </div>
            <div className="ex-past">
                <h4>past</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="ex-current">
                <h4>current</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="ex-future">
                <span className="future-span">No future exhibitions planned at the moment. Keep an eye on this page for updates!</span>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
```

imported file exhibitions-nav.js

```
const pastIndex = document.querySelector('.ex-past');
const currentIndex = document.querySelector('.ex-current');
const futureIndex = document.querySelector('.ex-future');

export function setPastOn(){
    pastIndex.style.display = 'block';
    currentIndex.style.display = 'none';
    futureIndex.style.display = 'none';
}

export function setCurrentOn(){
    pastIndex.style.display = 'none';
    currentIndex.style.display = 'block';
    futureIndex.style.display = 'none';
}
    
export function setFutureOn(){
    pastIndex.style.display = 'none';
    currentIndex.style.display = 'none';
    futureIndex.style.display = 'block';
}
```

css (just the part that matters)

```
.ex-past{
    display: none;
}

.ex-current{
    display: block;
}

.ex-future{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: read about virtual dom of react js will know why this happening

Comment: Check out the `useState` hook.  You basically want to set the state of whatever is current and apply classes accordingly.  You shouldn't need anything that's currently in `exhibitions-nav.js` when you're done.  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html